# javascript Custom function for array

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Can someone explain why this works:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'getRandom', {
    value: function(){return this[randomInt(0, this.length)]}
})
```

But why this doesn't works?

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'getRandom', {
    value: () => this[randomInt(0, this.length)]
})
```

Comment: The `this` keyword gives a different value in arrow functions compared to regular functions.  [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)